# 403 Hotlinking is forbidden

Tags: html, hotlinking

We have a website that generates simple links based in anchor tag to another site.

But, when we click in these links, the following error is displayed:

```
Error 403 Hotlinking is forbidden
Hotlinking is forbidden
Guru Meditation:
XID: 2586645211
Varnish cache server
```

We already check the CPANEL\SECURITY and HOTLINKS are DISABLED.

What could be happening?

Thanks everybody!

Comment: Just to be clear about this, the *other site* is giving you a 403?  Are you in control of the other site?

Comment: No, I don't have control about the other site. Users must to publish ads that have links to this site (the ad is published in my site). See example: http://www.brasiltelexfree.com.br/an.php?ad=queroagora&id=1295dd7401. And then, click in the link www.telexfree.com/ad/queroagora in the opened page. You will see the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to talk to the support team of the other site.

Hotlinking "protection" is done by analysing the `Referer:` field of the HTTP request.  When an image on one site (`one.example.com`) is linked from another site (`two.example.com`) like this:

```
<img src="http://one.example.com/image.jpg">
```

The `Referer:` field of the image request is set to `Referer: http://two.example.com/`.

If this field does not match a list of allowed referrers, the request is denied.

The `Referer:` field is set the same way when you click on a link.

The key thing to understand here is that *your* website is not in the allowed referrers list in *their* website's configuration.  There's nothing you can change in your configuration that can fix this.